# To start Microphone in Pebble Classic?

Tags: microphone, pebble

There is the setting in Pebble's settings where you can replace Music with Microphone. 
However, I have not managed to start recording of voice in any mode: phone not logged in vs phone logged in with password. 
I am using Android with Samsung Galaxy G4. 
I have the latest Android in the phone.

How can you start microphone in Pebble classic and Android?

Comment: Posting as a comment since I have not personally tested this solution but you should be able to use Tasker and PebbleTasker to create a shortcut to a task that starts voice recording.

Comment: @MichelfrancisBustillos Hi, you do not need PebbleTasker here. See the answer below.

Comment: 'twas just a suggestion on one way it could be done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install *Recordense* application in Pebble and *Recordense Light* in Android. You can also tag your recordings during recording, which is useful.